# how to delete the cell in table view

Tags: iphone, ios

Can some one suggest what is the problem in my code.....

self.modleClass.foldersAray have one object and tableview have one section and one row

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

        // Delete the row from the data source
        [self.tableview setEditing:YES animated:YES];

        [self.modleClass.foldersAray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:YEs];

        [tableView reloadData];
   }
}
```

I am getting error as below.

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (1) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (1), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'
```

Answer (score 3):

Do like this,

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

      if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

          [self.modleClass.foldersAray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

          [tableView reloadData];
      }
}
```

it is more enough.........

Comment: i do like that but cell not deleted...it displays same state of when i clicked edit button...

Answer (score 2):

If your tableView is based on the `foldersAray`, then removing an object from this array and reloading the tableview will result in the deletion of this cell.
You could remove the line:

```
[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:YEs];
```

Answer (score 1):

This error means, that you must update you datasource (array with data, dictionary or whatever you use)

For example: 
You have 5 cells before delete and 5 object in dataArray. Before call to `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:` we must remove object from dataArray, that associated with this cell and only then call `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:`. Also instead use `[tableView reloadData]`, use

```
[tableView beginUpdates];
[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
[tableView endUpdates];
```

P.S. I see, that you remove object from your datasource, so check it carefully, maybe you miss something

Answer (score 1):

If you want animation try this, if you dont want animation use @Mountain Lion's answer.

```
 -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle
 forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath  {

       if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) 
         {
             [self.modleClass.foldersAray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
             [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
       } 
 }
```

And if you have edit button on navigation, you should call

> [self.tableView setEditing:YES animated:YES];

inside of your method to start editting.

Answer (score 1):

IF the memory it takes does not matter for you... then you can dramatically delete (hide) cell by setting height to 0.

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.row%2) {
        return 0;
    }
    return 100;
}
```

P.S: above dummy code will dramatically delete alternate cells.